# Java Regex: Match text between two strings strictly inner block

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need a regex which matches between two strings but takes the inner block only. I tried using reluctant quantifier but it did not work.

Here is an example:

```
<div>
    Hi
</div>
<div class = "quote">
    This is mail.
    <hr tabindex="-1">
    <div color="r">
        <b>From:</b>xyz<br>
        <b>Sent:</b>xyz PM<br>
        <b>To:</b>xyz<br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used this regex but it did not work (with DOTALL matching, so that "." matches newline as well)

```
<div.*(From:.*Sent:.*To:.*)*?</div>
```

Above regex is matching everything since the input text starts with `<div>` and ends with `</div>`, but I need the  just above and below the pattern specified inside the bracket.

So I need the output to be:

```
<div color="r">
        <b>From:</b>xyz<br>
        <b>Sent:</b>xyz PM<br>
        <b>To:</b>xyz<br><br>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe if you just repeatedly match for `<div.*div>` and then use some Java code to see if it found the right one. Maybe another regex or some `.indexOf()` calls. Repeat until you find the right one.

Comment: I dont think thats a great idea. Thing is if I repeatedly call `<div.*</div>`, it will match in the very first `<div>` because of the use of `.*`.. I guess....

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to parse HTML using regex.

If you know what you're doing then you can use following `String#replaceAll` call:

```
html.replaceAll
           ("(?i)(?s).*?(<div\\s*color.*?From:.*?Sent:.*?To:.*?</div>).*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm expanding on my comment so you'll see what I mean:

```
  public String findText(String htmlString) {
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("<div.*</div>");
      Matcher m = patt.matcher(htmlString);
      while (m.find()) {
        String text = m.group(1);
        // check whether the value of text is the div you want
        if (text.indexOf("color") < text.indexOf(">")) { //... or something similar
           return (text);
        }
      }
    return null;
   }
```